# silverstripe 4 server error after removing module

Tags: fluent, silverstripe-4

I'm having problems with using fluent in Silverstripe 4. So I tested to install different versions of fluent to see if I was able to get it working. The version of Silverstripe is 4.1.1.

After uninstalling fluent again, I get "server error" and I can't see anything in the php logs and when trying to run in dev mode, I don't see any difference.

One puzzling thing is that a folder named "themes" appeared in the root folder. I think that it was added by composer during the module installation, but I'm not sure. But I do know that git listed the themes folder as an untracked file. Which suggests that it was automatically added. So I removed that folder when uninstalling the module.

**Now I'm not sure what to do. I would want to restore the database as it was before installing fluent (I've tried to add language to see if fluent was working). Or at least get back to square one.
How do people usually do when working with Silverstripe and testing modules?**

What I've done so far:

1. Checked the php logs. No errors found.
2. Added "Director::set_environment_type("dev");"  to _config.php, without seeing any difference when loading the page.
3. Tested to load the page with ?dev=1 without any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `composer update` and now the site is working. Might be one thing to test for silverstripe noobs (like me).